# Count number of word occurrences in a string

Tags: c#, string, count, words

I have this project in .Net C#, where I have to count the number of word occurances in a string. I get a KeyNotFoundException where at a point where I am incrementing the variable to show how many times a word is repeated.
The code is as follows: scroll down for the error

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> Process(string phrase)
{
    Dictionary<string, int> wordsAndCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    string[] words = phrase.Replace("\"", "").Replace("'", "").Replace(".", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("\n", "").Split(' ');
    for (int index = 0; index <= words.Length; index++)
    {
        string word = words[index];
        wordsAndCount[word] = wordsAndCount[word] + 1;
    }
    Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in wordsAndCount.OrderByDescending((s) => s.Key))
        dictionary.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);

    wordsAndCount = dictionary;
    return wordsAndCount;
}
```

}

error at

```
wordsAndCount[word] = wordsAndCount[word] + 1; KeyNotFoundException was unhandled
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with the error i think. anw tried it, no luck, thanks anw

Comment: The error seems pretty self explanatory.  It says that the key isn't found in the dictionary, because you're fetching the value of a key you haven't yet set.

Comment: don't really see what I have to do here...

Comment: You have to not ask for keys that don't exist in the dictionary using the indexer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop contains two problems:

- You can't use a key if it doesn't exist (Test with ContainsKey)
- You should loop until index < words.Length

  ```
  for (int index = 0; index < words.Length; index++)
  {
      string word = words[index];
      if(!wordsAndCount.ContainsKey(word))
          wordsAndCount.Add(word, 1);
      else
          wordsAndCount[word]++;
  }
  ```

You could also trim away a bit of code using this approach to sort your dictionary

```
var temp = wordsAndCount.OrderByDescending (ac => ac.Key);
return temp.ToDictionary (t => t.Key, t => t.Value);
```

Comment: good implementation, was trying to develop that but couldn't! thanks anyway

Comment: what would this enable me? the last part

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Number of occurrences of string B in string A.

```
var NumberOfOccurrences = A.Split(new string[] { B }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length - 1;
```